# How to make Ruby partially parse the source code?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a script in Ruby which interactively generate some input data for a program. The idea is use QtRuby when it exists, otherwise console is used. What I tried is to

```
begin
  require "Qt4"
rescue LoadError => load_err
  puts "Qt not found, using console"
end

class ConsoleDefine
  # console code
end

class QtDefine < Qt::Widget
  # GUI code
end
```

but the interpreter refused my code when Qt4 does not exist. is there a way to deal it similar to C++, like:

```
#ifdef QT4
class qt4gui 
{
    // some code
};
#else
class qt4gui
{
    // dummy
};
#endif // Qt4
```

Comment: Source files are just source files; did you try wrapping it in something that tries to evaluate something from the package in question?

Comment: The `class` keyword in Ruby is *just an expression* (this differs from languages like Java/C# where it is a declaration). As such they can be nested in other statements/expressions: `if defined? Qt; class QtDefine < Qt::Widget; ..; end; end` .. now, is this "good"? Well, that's what the real answers are for :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use require to your advantage:

```
begin
  require "Qt4"
  require "my_lib/qt4"
rescue LoadError => load_err
  puts "Qt not found, using console"
  require "my_lib/console"
end
```

Create the two files:

```
# my_lib/console.rb
class ConsoleDefine
  # console code
end

# my_lib/qt4.rb
class QtDefine < Qt::Widget
  # GUI code
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As @pst said, you don't need a preprocessor in Ruby, since it is dynamic. So:

```
begin
  require "Qt4"
   class QtDefine < Qt::Widget
     # GUI code
   end
rescue LoadError => load_err
  puts "Qt not found, using console"
   class ConsoleDefine
     # console code
   end
end
```

Comment: That was my first idea, but now you have two different systems in your main file cluttered in some barely-visible `rescue`.

Comment: That what @xis19 wanted. In C preprocessor, the file looks the same.